# How to get the last element of an array and show the rest?

Tags: arrays, perl

How do I get the last element of an array and show the rest of the elements?

Like this :

```
@myArray = (1,1,1,1,1,2);
```

Expected output  :

```
SomeVariable1 = 11111
SomeVariable2 = 2
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
# print last element
print $myArray[-1];

# joined rest of the elements
print join "", @myArray[0 .. $#myArray-1] if @myArray >1;
```

If you don't mind modifying the array,

```
# print last element
print pop @myArray;

# joined rest of the elements
print join "", @myArray;
```

Comment: thanks, tried out the first one. exactly what i needed. cheers

Comment: Don't you need an arrow in that first one? `print $myArray->[-1]` ?

Comment: No, that would be required in case `$myArray` is variable and an array reference at that. `use strict;` to catch errors related to misappropriate use use of `$var` when `@var` is the variable you actually use.

Answer (score 1):

[Сухой27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/mpapec) has given you [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26481754/725418). I wanted to add that if you are creating a structured output, it might be nice to use a hash:

```
my @myArray = (1,1,1,1,1,2);

my %variables = (
    SomeVariable1 => [ @myArray[0 .. $#myArray -1] ],
    SomeVariable2 => [ $myArray[-1] ]
);

for my $key (keys %variables) {
    print "$key => ",@{ $variables{$key} },"\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
SomeVariable1 => 11111
SomeVariable2 => 2
```